# How to close a chrome.extension.Port?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the checklist for converting from a background page to an [event page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html), [#9](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html#transition) says:

> If you're using [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#connect), be sure to close unused message ports. The event page will not shut down until all message ports are closed.

How is a [`chrome.extension.Port`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#type-Port) closed?

Comment: A disconnect method was added but not yet supported in the current stable channel of Chrome. When the page of either end of the port unloads, the port is automatically disconnected.

Comment: Why not provide an answer.